# How to avoid casting of interfaces with good design?

Tags: java, interface, casting, adapter

I have a problem with the interfaces. In particular, I use a library that requires the IMultiPoint interface, but my class implements ILocation, as shown below:

[IMultiPoint interface (library source code)](https://github.com/heineman/algorithms-nutshell-2ed/blob/master/JavaCode/src/algs/model/IMultiPoint.java)

```
/* 
 * My custom interface: the ILocation is a "class" of objects that can be 
 * represented in two different systems: the plane (with coordinates x and 
 * y, expressed in meters) and the signal space (the number of dimensions 
 * is the number of bluetooth beacons).
*/
public interface ILocation {

    // returns the name of the region where the point is located
    String getRegion();

    void setRegion(String region);

    // returns the Cartesian coordinates x and y (expressed in meters) in the plane
    double[] getCartesianCoordinates();

    void setCartesianCoordinates (double x, double y);

    /* returns all dimensions in signal space (ordered for 
       beacon/dimension), with their relative values of power (rssi) */
    SortedMap<IBeacon, Integer> getAllRssi();

    void setRssi(Map<IBeacon, Integer> dimensions);

}
```

So I have an object that can be ILocation or IMultiPoint.
The two interfaces not only have different signature methods, but have additional ad hoc methods.

I thought about using the adapter pattern, with use of [Hyperpoint class of library](https://github.com/heineman/algorithms-nutshell-2ed/blob/master/JavaCode/src/algs/model/nd/Hyperpoint.java)

```
public class LocationAdapter implements IMultiPoint {

    private ILocation location;
    private IMultiPoint multiPoint;

    public LocationAdapter(ILocation location) {
        this.location = location;
        double[] coordinates = Doubles.toArray(location.getAllRssi().values());
        // Default IMultiPoint implementation, provided by the library
        this.multiPoint = new Hyperpoint(coordinates);
    }

    int dimensionality() {
        return this.multiPoint.dimensionality();
    }

    double getCoordinate(int dx) {
        return this.multiPoint.getCoordinate(dx);
    }

    double distance(IMultiPoint imp) {
        return this.multiPoint.distance(imp);
    }

    double[] raw() {
        return this.multiPoint.raw();        
    }

    // To obtain original object
    ILocation removeAdapter() {
        return this.location;
    }

}
```

This solution allows me to pass an ILocation object to the library (via adapter), but when the library returns me an IMultiPoint object (for example when I call the [nearest method](https://github.com/heineman/algorithms-nutshell-2ed/blob/master/JavaCode/src/algs/model/kdtree/KDTree.java#L224) of [KDTree class of library](https://github.com/heineman/algorithms-nutshell-2ed/blob/master/JavaCode/src/algs/model/kdtree/KDTree.java)) I should casting it in LocationAdapter and call removeAdapter() method to obtain original ILocation object, which I can use in outside of library.
This solution adds an overhead, because initially I load in memory the ILocation objects from the db, later for each object I create the adapter and pass it to the library. The objects stored in the db are many (about 1000), considering that I'm developing on android.

Another solution is to create a Location class that implements ILocation and extends Hyperpoint, but so I am forced to use the cast and, in addition, if I change the library in the future, I should also change this class.

What should I do? Where am I wrong? I'd like to make a good design.

I'm sorry for this long question.

Comment: Could you add an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? IMO it is really hard to understand your question. You are asking about `overhead`, `database, `memory`, `library`, `andorid` and more subjects. It is really hard to tell what your actual question is.

Comment: I am confused your 'distance' method is returning 'double' and not 'IMultiPoint'.

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake, i edited the question. I use a class called KDTree (a particular search binary tree), which has a nearest(IMultiPoint imp) that returns the closest IMultiPoint in the tree.
Should I add another code or a uml class diagram for sake of completeness?

Answer (score 0):

I think this Adapter should implement both the interfaces so that any instance of this can be substituted for any of those interfaces. As such you might not need any casting.

Comment: Even if I use the adapater pattern I have to cast. For example, if I use the [nearest method of the KDTree class](https://github.com/heineman/algorithms-nutshell-2ed/blob/master/JavaCode/src/algs/model/kdtree/KDTree.java#L224), I pass the adapter as argument and i receive an IMultiPoint (adapter).
[example code](https://pastebin.com/ewHMysU3)